# What is the best way to quantify the goodness of fit between the data and my model?

Tags: regression-coefficients, goodness-of-fit

I am modeling the total fluid rate at the bottom of an oil well using a roughly exponential model (mixed with other terms representing an input signal). Here is one example (blue circles are the observed data and black solid line is my model):

[image]

In order to determine the goodness of this fit, I plotted the observed data vs the modeled data and calculated the coefficient of determination, $R^2$; however, this does not seem to do justice to my model because very small or negative $R^2$ values occur a lot ($R^2 = -0.37$ for the above example). BTW, because the data is extremely noisy, it is sufficient that my model is able to track the observed data. Please help me fix this problem or find a better way to quantify the quality of my fit.

Comment: How are you getting $R^2<0$?

Answer (score -1):

You should try fitting a Quadric Equation to your data which is quite flexible to get the perfect trend of any data and then calculate R square value which won't be negative or even less.

Comment: I am not sure we are on the same page. I have already fit the data with my model. I need a measure of the goodness of the fit.